# How can I return object values the corect way to do it

Tags: javascript, object, return

I'm trying to return a global variable and set an object in an array.

Could anyone explain what I am doing wrong to retrieve the global variable `outPutArray`? It become undefined when I try to return it.

```js
var outPutArray = {};
var goAjax = function(data, filePath) {
  data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: filePath, //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      for (x in data) {
        outPutArray[x] = data[x];
      }
      //logs the the wanted value
      console.log('inside ' + outPutArray['json']);
    }
  });
};

goAjax.prototype.getValue = function() {
  console.log('outside ' + outPutArray['json']);
  //logs undefined ??
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: are you sure the object data (and its replicateoutPutArray) has a property named "json" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would like to thank every  one who tried to help me .The answer is to use a parameter that would work as an interface in java to fire a function inside another function or a method to be fired inside other method .

```js
 /**
   *This is a constructor of javascript firing a server side PHP script.
   * 
 * @param {Object} filePath PHP file path
   */
 var AjsToPHP = function(filePath){
 this.filePath = filePath;
   };
      
       
 /**
  * 
  * Firing server side PHP script and return respond as an array.
 * @param {Object} data Input an array of object to go as POST command.
 * @param {Object} response An interface function to return the respond value.
  */
  AjsToPHP.prototype.PHP_PROCESS_RETURN = function(data,response){
    var PHP_RETURNS= {}; 
    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: this.filePath, //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
      for (x in data) {
       PHP_RETURNS[x] = data[x];
 
        }
          response(PHP_RETURNS);

    
      }
    });
  };



/**
 * 
 * Firing server side PHP script and return respond OK if it success.
 * @param {Object} data Input an array of object to go as POST command.
 * @param {Object} response An interface function to return the respond value.
 */
 AjsToPHP.prototype.PHP_PROCESS = function(data,response){
    var PHP_RETURNS= ""; 
    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: this.filePath, //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {     
       PHP_RETURNS= "ok";     
          response(PHP_RETURNS);

      }
    });
 };
```

An example

```js
<script src="jsToPHP.js"></script>  
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
$("document").ready(function(){


        var data = {
      "action": "test",
      "Name" :"abdulla"
        };



var obj = new AjsToPHP("response.php");

obj.PHP_PROCESS_RETURN(data,function(PHP_RESPONE){ 
 alert('inside '+PHP_RESPONE['json']);
});


obj.PHP_PROCESS(data,function(PHP_RESPONE){
 
 alert(PHP_RESPONE);
 
 
});
```

The response.php script

```html
<?php



function is_ajax() {
  return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}



if (is_ajax()) {
    
       
  if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) { //Checks if action value exists
    $action = $_POST["action"];
  
    switch($action) { //This is how we are able to create different function according to different function call
      case "test": test_function(); break;
    }
  }
  
  
  
  
}



function test_function(){
 

 //this a correct way of creating an associative array.
  $name = $_POST["Name"];
  $return["name"] = $name;
  $return["favorite_beverage"] = "Coke";
  $return["favorite_restaurant"] = "McDonald's";  
  $return["json"] = json_encode($return); 
  
  //return data to javascript
  echo json_encode($return); 
}













?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's undefined when you try to return it because AJAX is asynchronous.

See [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/218196), and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/2714730), or Google "return AJAX response" or something similar.

It boils down to the fact that asynchronous calls happen outside of the normal event loops and execution, so when you set a global variable with an asynchronous response, there's no way for JavaScript to "know" when it'll get there.